# 16 ports rackable gigabit switch(es) for 10 inches wall mounting cabinet: does it even exist?

Tags: switch, home-electronics

I've recently acquired a [Digitus DN-10-05U-1](http://www.digitus.info/en/products/network-and-server-cabinet-systems/wallmount-cabinets/unique-line/dn-10-05u-1/) (10" wide compact rack) to setup my home's network.  Now I'd like to rack some proper 16 ports gigabit switch in there, but I'm really having a hard time finding anything fitting the cabinet.  Everything I could find so far was either too wide, too deep, not rackable, limited to 8 ports, apparently super cheap, don't sell in my country (Belgium), ...  You name it.

Any recommendation ?

Comment: Why wouldn't something like this work?: TP-Link 16-Port Gigabit Ethernet Unmanaged Rackmount Switch (TL-SG1016) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002HAJQGA/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_heE0ybEVTG493

Comment: It's way too wide for a 10" cabinet.

Comment: Oops! I thought you meant 10" deep! My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions I've found so far.  They are all

- Gigabit
- 16 ports
- sold WITHOUT 10" rack mounting kit

[Intellinet 16-Port Gigabit 561068](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B018X9RU0W/).
L x W x H: 21.5 x 13.3 x 44 millimeters

[Longshine LCS-GS8116-A](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B006GUN776/).
L x W x H: 216 x 133 x 42 millimeters

[ZyXEL GS-1100-16](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0046BAVQ2/).
L x W x H: 215 x 133 x 42 millimeters

[Buffalo BS-GU2016](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OLUJGDM).
L x W x H: 215 x 13 x 42 millimeters

Regarding the rack mounting kit, I think (hope) that magnaroute LLC could come to the rescue, especially with that kind of product: [magnaroute LLC FX-17 Multi-Vendor Rack Mount Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C9O1T5O).
[image: magnaroute rack mount kit]
The other option is to pick a product that ships with 19" rack mount kit and adapt the kit (cut and pierce).